# Console.log the result of a function set Into a Variable

Tags: javascript, debugging

Meanwhile learning how to debug I need to see in the browser the result of an Operation Saved into a variable.

```
 var res=    function() {
            [].forEach.call(this.slider, function(el) {
                return el.className = 'item';
            })}.bind(this);
```

this.slider has the following:
[image]

if I `console.log (res)`
I get :

[image]

I would like to Receive the Changes made to this.slider inside the res function so I could compare the Original and the new value.

Comment: What's wrong with outputting `console.log(this.slider)` before and after the operation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, Im just trying to learn how to console.log things in the browser so I could learn to debug. Im just trying to display the before and then the after of the operations made inside Res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally just log before and after the code that manipulates your object:

```
var res = function() {
    console.log('before:', this.slider);

    [].forEach.call(this.slider, function(el) {
        return el.className = 'item';
    });

    console.log('after:', this.slider);
}.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`res` is a function.  you need to define the function separately and then call it and save the result in `res` if you want it to be there.

for example,

```
function example() {
        [].forEach.call(this.slider, function(el) {
            return el.className = 'item';
        })}.bind(this);

res = example();
console.log(res);
```

Also, your question is very hard to read.

Edit:  your question is hard enough to read that I apparently didn't understand it, I don't think this is the answer you're looking for.  Please reformat with code snippets instead of images.

Edit 2: Andre Dion is correct, this would still log 'undefined' since you don't return anything from the function.

Comment: This would still return `undefined` since it doesn't explicitly have a `return` statement and because `Array.prototype.forEach` also returns `undefined`.

Comment: yes, I was just showing that the poster was console logging the function itself instead of whatever result it would return

Comment: Im trying to make it clearer. Thank you for responding